# How can I get a 3 smallest unique rows of big csv (>10 millions rows) file with Apache Spark/PySpark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am PhD student from Poland. I have one question about Apache Spark/Pyspark 2. How can I get a 3 smallest unique (unique text, not length) rows of big csv file (>10 millions rows) with Apache Spark/PySpark 2?

**dat.csv** csv file example:

```
name,id
abc,1
abcd,2
abcde,3
ab,4
ab,4
```

1 Get list of lengths for each unique rows in data frame:

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sql_context = SQLContext(sc)
df = sql_context.read.csv(
        path="/home/rkorniichuk/data.csv", sep=',', encoding="UTF-8",
        quote='"', escape='"', header=True, inferSchema=True,
        ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace=True, ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace=False,
        mode="FAILFAST")

def get_row_lenght(row):
    lenght = 0
    for column in row:
        lenght += len(str(column))
    return lenght`

rows_lenght_list = [df.foreach(get_row_lenght)]`

>>> rows_length_list
>>> [None]
```

And we have a problem here, because I wanna fill `rows_length_list` value as `[4, 5, 6, 3, 3]`.

2 Sort `rows_length_list`:

```
rows_length_list.sort()

>>> rows_length_list
>>> [3, 4, 5, 6]
```

3 Get max value for csv file samples rows:

```
>>> rows_length_list[3-1]
>>> 5
```

4 Get 3 samples with length <=5 characters:

```
abc,1 # TRUE
abcd,2 # TRUE
abcde,3 # FALSE
ab,4 # TRUE and BREAK
ab,4
```

**Can I realized it only with [Data Frame](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame) (w/o SQL requests)?**

Comment: can you please format your code blocks? It is unreadable as it is.

Comment: It is my maximum skill level with Stack Overflow code blocks:(

Comment: 2 @mtoto done. Thanks for your comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `concat()` to concatenate all columns into one string, wrapped inside `length()` to calculate the length of the resulting new variable:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import concat, length, col

df.withColumn("row_len", length(concat(*df.columns))) \
  .filter(col("row_len") <= 5) \
  .dropDuplicates() \
  .sort("row_len") \
  .show()
+----+---+-------+
|name| id|row_len|
+----+---+-------+
|  ab|  4|      3|
| abc|  1|      4|
|abcd|  2|      5|
+----+---+-------+
```

If you have more than `3` rows, you could use `.take(3)` to instead of `.show()` to get the 3 unique rows with the smallest `row_len`.

Comment: Thank you very much @mtoto. Do you know how can I automatically concatenate all columns in DateFrame or get DataFrame columns name?

Comment: See update, you can access the list of column names by `df.columns`, which we can pass as strings to `concat()` using the `*` operator.

Comment: @moto it was exactly that I tried realized few evenings. Thank you very much for your extra fast help and Spark DataFrame syntax introduction.